# Microsoft OneNote for Mac: shortcut to add To Do

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote

I used to press `Cmd`+`1` (on macOS) to add a checkboxes (To Do) and tick them. This does not work since the last update (version 16.24).

I cannot see it on the page [Keyboard Shortcuts in OneNote for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-onenote-for-mac-20fa1619-0f1c-4f83-a3cc-41e12b366f2f).

I managed to do those operations using a shortcut (after trial and error) but I can't find what's the new shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a regression, it's working again in Microsoft OneNote for Mac version 16.25 (19051201).